# CBR traffic does not get added

Tags: tcl, ns2

The wireless-flooding.tcl file in ns2-allinone2.34/ns2.34/tcl/ex is running succesfully but with no traffic among other nodes. The programme implements a simple flooding which runs succesfully.But when I added a chunk of code for generating CBR traffic  the error is showing as follows:
    num_nodes is set 24
    INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead

```
can't read "node_(0)": no such variable
    while executing
    "$ns attach-agent $node_($i) $udp_($j) "
    ("for" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"

for {set i 0} {$i < $num_nodes} {incr i} { 
            set udp_($j) [new Agent/UDP] 
            $ns attach-agent $node_($i) $udp_($j) 
            set null_($j)..."
(file "wireless-flooding.tcl" line 173)
```

For the CBR traffic I added the chunk

```
set j 0
   for {set i 0} {$i < $num_nodes} {incr i} { 
   set udp_($j) [new Agent/UDP] 
    $ns attach-agent $node_($i) $udp_($j) 
    set null_($j) [new Agent/Null] 
    $ns attach-agent $node_([expr $i+1]) $null_($j) 

     set cbr_($j) [new Application/Traffic/CBR] 
     puts "cbr_($j) has been created over udp_($j)" 
     $cbr_($j) set packet_size_ 512 
     $cbr_($j) set interval_ 1 
     $cbr_($j) set rate_ 10kb 
     $cbr_($j) set ransom_ flase 
     $cbr_($j) attach-agent $udp_($j) 
     $ns connect $udp_($j) $null_($j) 
     puts "$udp_($j) and $null_($j) agents has been connected each other" 
     $ns at 1.0  "$cbr_($j)  start" 

     set j [expr $j+1] 
     set i [expr $i+1] 

 }
```

Comment: Can you post the full code here?

Comment: Thank god,the problem got solved with much analysis